# GIF output requires libvips with support for ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, sharp, vips

I'm working on building a website with Gatsby and whenever I try to build I get this error. I have installed libvips with Homebrew and it automatically includes ImageMagick. I then deleted sharp from node_modules and reinstalled sharp, but I still get this error. I'm new to doing anything on the command line so any help is appreciated!

```
npm sharp -v
7.16.0

vips -v
vips-8.10.6-Tue Mar 23 20:52:58 UTC 2021

magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-14 Q16 x86_64 2021-05-31 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/install.html

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I came up with a similar problem.

1. First check the existing libvips version using `pkg-config --modversion vips-cpp`.
2. All version after 8 I think supports gif. Refer this doc `https://www.libvips.org/install.html#building-libvips-from-a-source-tarball`
3. Check for your node version make sure to bump to 12 and also delete the older sharp from our package.json. Uninstall sharp and after libvips is installed reinstall sharp.
4. Now the sharp library would have used the newly updated libvips and the libvips has support for gif. Refer documentation from point 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install sharp with a custom libvips, see:

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#custom-libvips

During install, sharp will execute this command to detect your libvips ready to build against it:

```
pkg-config --modversion vips-cpp
```

So try running that before running npm and verify that it prints the correct libvips version number. If it fails with "package not found", you probably haven't set your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

It's worth bearing in mind that libvips with imagemagick enabled can be less secure. Be rather cautious about processing untrusted image data.

Comment: I appreciate this response, but I found somewhere in the Gatsby docs that the image plugin doesn't support gifs or svg. I ended up converting the gifs to png. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [v0.30.0, released on 2022-02-01](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/changelog#v0300---1st-february-2022), the prebuilt binaries included in sharp support GIFs, so you don’t have to worry about other dependencies anymore.